# Storing a Value of a Set analysis expression in a Variable

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am struggling with storing  a set analysis expression's value in a variable.

I want to store below expression's value in a variable so that i can use that further for some calculations.

```
Min({< Data_Period = {'Weekly'},Formatted_Date = {'>$(=$(vSelectedWeek))'}>} Date,2)
```

The above expression works fine if i use it in a text box on a sheet tab. However, it is not working if i try to store its value in a variable and use that variable.

```
Set vW1 = Min({< Data_Period = {'Weekly'},Formatted_Date = {'>$(=$(vSelectedWeek))'}>} Date,2);
```

Here  vSelectedWeek  is being calculated as follows:

```
Set vSelectedWeek = Date(Weekstart(Only(BaseData_Date)),'dd/MM/YYYY');
```

Please advise if i am doing anything wrong or is there any other way around to achieve the same?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your var is truly working with that expression then try creating an input box object, define your var there and add the expression in the right column.

That should work.

If you find my answer to be pretty simple or not the way you want it, checking this link might help: https://community.qlik.com/thread/198307